# Displaying image in picturebox using Matrox imaging library in c#

Tags: c#, imaging

i am developing an winformapp for image processing in c# VB2017 using MIL. My query is how do to display an image in picturebox using MIL.

MIL does provide a method called `MdispSelectWindow()` wherein you pass the display id, the buffer you wish to display and the clientwindowhandle but i can't seem to pass picturebox1.handle to it.

I also tried to dock a picturebox on a panel and then use it but that is also not working.

What could be the possible solution to this?

Comment: Can you show the definition of MdispSelectWindow()  ?  The Docs are locked.

Comment: OK, did you try that? (Use pictureBox1.Handle)? If that doesn't work, what happens?? Also: You could use a Panel instead of a PBox, not nest the pb..

Comment: @TaW its definition is  'public static void MdispSelectWindow(MIL_ID DisplayId, MIL_ID ImageBufId, IntPtr ClientWindowHandle);' MIL.MdispSelectWindow(MilDisplay, MilImage, panel1.Handle); Select an image buffer to display in a user-defined window.

Comment: i am using a panel only, but i want to try with picturebox. even if i simply use pb nothing shows up.

Comment: _i am using a panel only_ And? Does that work?? Also: Are you sure the LilDisplay actually has an image loaded?

Comment: yes, panel works like this: MIL.MdispSelectWindow(MilDisplay, MilImage, panel1.Handle). but if i try to do the same with pb, it doesnt work.And yes, display has the image loaded

Comment: Hm, that is weird. Any reason you want to switch to  PictureBox? Anything you did to PBox? Set an Image (Or BackgroundImage)?

Comment: i want to use pB because its easier to manipulate. I can set the image to stretch so i don't miss out on the quality of image(which happens in panel).Secondly when i zoom in to the picture then i will get automatic scrollbars(which i tried doing on panel but isn't happening).

Comment: I doubt that any of what you wrote holds. a) Are you sure that PBox has a better stretching/zooming quality for its Image than Panel for its BackgroundImage? And using AutoScrollxyz properties should allow scrollbars as well. b) It looks as if passing a Handle to the MdispSelectWindow function will let it create an overlay on the control; what makes you believe that any of the layout capabilities of PBox will work with that? - Mind, I'm not sure but I do doubt it..

Comment: i am using certain functions by matrox imaging library(MIL)  for image processing like brightness contrast etc. one of them is zoom, for this i am using Mdispzoom() . i am able to achieve the required zoom with the help of this.But i dont get the automatic scrollbars of panel.

Comment: To make a Panel scrollable do this: Set it to AutoScroll and set the AutoScrollMinsize to the full size of the Image. Set the BackgroundImageLayout to Center, Zoom or Stretch.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, my image is real time. does that mean i have to set autoscrollminsize to the size of the current image every time? also what would setting Background imagelayout to cener/zoom/stretch do?

Comment: Why not try it? It will make the panel show a zoomed etc version, like a pbox will.